# Crashlytics compatible with Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, crash-reports, crashlytics

Is it possible to integrate Crashlytics with Xcode 6.2 ?
If no, is there any free crash reporting tool that can be integrated with an iOS that runs only on Xcode 6.2 ?

This is for an enterprise app which will not be submitted to the Apple appstore.

Comment: You are aware that Apple requires Apps to be build with Xcode 7 if you plan to submit to the AppStore.

Comment: Yes, but this is an enterprise app and not needed to be submitted to the apple appstore.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Just wanted to confirm that we no longer support Xcode 6.

Answer (score 0):

So, even if Crashlytics (now part of Fabric, by Twitter) is great, if it doesn't fit your needs then you can browse through the alternatives until you find one compatible:

- [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios) by Google
- [SplunkMint](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SplunkMint-iOS) (was Bugsense)
- [Crittercism](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CrittercismSDK) (now Apteligent)
- [Instabug](https://instabug.com/)
- [HockeyApp](https://www.hockeyapp.net/features/crashreports/) by Microsoft
- [PLCrashReporter](https://www.plcrashreporter.org/)
- [AppDynamics](https://www.appdynamics.com/mobile/)

Also, migrating your project to be compatible with a newer version of Xcode shouldn't be that hard...